# How to display a constantly changing image file in a browser without refresh flicker?

Tags: html, image, canvas, refresh

I'm displaying an image (from a file) on the browser using html... I have another program that keeps taking a screenshot of my screen and storing it as an image file "image.jpeg". I am displaying this image on the browser periodically using setTimeout. However the image is not changing on the browser..

Here is my code... I have used an Image object so that a new image is loaded everytime the javascript function runs, however that does not seem to be working...

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/JavaScript">

var x=0, y=0;
var canvas, context, img;

function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod)
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("x");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.src = "image.jpeg";
    context.drawImage(img, x, y);
    x+=20; y+=20;
    //img.destroy();
    setTimeout("timedRefresh(1000)",timeoutPeriod);
}

</script>

<title>JavaScript Refresh Example</title>

</head>

<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(1000);">

<canvas id="x" width="600" height="600" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, when you set the `src` attribute of your image object, the image has not been loaded yet, you need to refresh your canvas when the `onload` of the image gets fired (when the image is done loading).

Secondly, the browser tries to use the cached image `image.jpeg`. To avoid that, add a bogus argument to the image URI.

For example :

```
var timeoutPeriod = 1000;
var imageURI = 'image.jpeg';
var x=0, y=0;
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("x");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.drawImage(img, x, y);
    x+=20; y+=20;
    setTimeout(timedRefresh,timeoutPeriod);
};

function timedRefresh() {
    // just change src attribute, will always trigger the onload callback
    img.src = imageURI + '?d=' + Date.now();
}
```

And then it should work.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea to use a bogus property in order to prevent using a cached image.

Answer (score 6):

Here a complete working example. Just configure `url` and `refeshInterval`. It uses [Yannick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438612/how-to-display-a-constantly-changing-image-file-in-a-browser-without-refresh-fli#answer-5438667)'s caching prevention and does not re-create the `img` object on every reload as suggested by [Piotr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438612/how-to-display-a-constantly-changing-image-file-in-a-browser-without-refresh-fli#answer-11645035).

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var url = "cam1.php"; //url to load image from
var refreshInterval = 1000; //in ms
var drawDate = true; //draw date string
var img;

function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        canvas.setAttribute("width", img.width)
        canvas.setAttribute("height", img.height)
        context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        if(drawDate) {
            var now = new Date();
            var text = now.toLocaleDateString() + " " + now.toLocaleTimeString();
            var maxWidth = 100;
            var x = img.width-10-maxWidth;
            var y = img.height-10;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.lineWidth = 2;
            context.strokeText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
            context.fillStyle = 'white';
            context.fillText(text, x, y, maxWidth);
        }
    };
    refresh();
}
function refresh()
{
    img.src = url + "?t=" + new Date().getTime();
    setTimeout("refresh()",refreshInterval);
}

</script>
<title>JavaScript Refresh Example</title>
</head>

<body onload="JavaScript:init();">
<canvas id="canvas"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the canvas element really cuts back on the flicker!

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to create the Image object every time in `timedRefresh()`. Just create one instance and constantly change its `src` attribute. In case of your code snippet, `img` would have to be global variable.

The main problem, though, is that you will still see flickering (but of different kind) in Opera. See: [Image source update in JavaScript with Opera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639656/image-source-update-in-javascript-with-opera)